# How to restrict who can merge to master on a github repo?

Tags: git, github

I have setup on my Github repo
a branch protection rule on master branch checking (activating) the following:

- Require pull request reviews before merging
- Required approving reviewers : 1
- Include administrators
- Restrict who can push to matching branches

I'm then in a situation that at least one from the team must approve a PR before someone can merge its own dev branch to master.

Apart from the above I would also want to select only some people that will have the permission to merge the reviewed and approved PR.
Not everyone having access to the repo.

Is it possible to set this up?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-branch-restrictions what is missing into the doc ?

Comment: I've read that and it's not that explicit...Maybe "Restrict who can push to matching branches" also meaning restrict who can merge to matching branch? And if I enable those people will they be able to push directly to master without PR?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests to add minimal validator and set  Require pull request reviews before merging.

Answer (score 10):

No, GitHub doesn't let you restrict who can perform a merge.  However, if you want to require a specific group of people to approve a PR before merging, use the [`CODEOWNERS` file](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) and require an approval from a code owner before merging in the branch protection settings.

For example, if you want all changes to be reviewed by the core team, you can use this in your `CODEOWNERS` file:

```
*  @my-org/core
```

Comment: but this will make every new branch created after that to request a review from code owner even though the base branch is not master

Comment: not AFAIK. the "Require review from Codeowners" is part of the branch protection rules, so it applies only to the branches (or branch pattern) you define in the protection rule. So you can restrict this to your main branch

Comment: I made a demo of how this setup works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1YLRieq7Y

Answer (score 6):

Merging of pull requests respect the branch protection rule of the target branch. So add the people who should be allowed to merge into the protection rule and you are good to go.[image]

[image]

Comment: More information please, how is this achieved? With what rule?

Comment: How do you accomplish this

Comment: Go to the repository in Github. Go to "Settings" -> "Branches" under "Code and automation", then check "Restrict who can push to matching branches"

Comment: This might actually do the job

Comment: Went to Settings | Branches | Code and automation - the word "restrict" does not appear anywhere on the page. How did you do this? And screenshots would be very helpful. TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen On your chosen repository, go to Settings -> Branches (Under code and automation) -> Edit (on your selected branch) and then check "Restrict who can push to matching branches"

Comment: @ogborstad Please look at the comments to the answer by LuigiB below - that restricts who can push, not who can merge. thanks

Comment: In case you cannot find this in your settings, keep in mind you need either GitHub Team or GitHub Free organization ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#restrict-who-can-push-to-matching-branches))

Comment: @DavidThielen Look at what [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#restrict-who-can-push-to-matching-branches) say: _"When status checks are required, the people, teams, and apps that have permission to push to a protected branch will still be **prevented from merging into the branch** when the required checks fail."_ So, to my understanding, this option *does* restrict who can merge.

Answer (score 4):

I also have requirement like you that I only want some specific people (not all collaborators) are allowed to approve changes to the main branch. And I did as follows for `Github Free public repository`:

- write a `Github Actions` file that check the name of person who runs it. If this is name of powerful collaborator, the Actions will succeed.

```
name: actions_on_main_branch
on: 
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
    branches:    
      - 'main'

jobs:
  job1:
    name: check_adminA
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NAME_ADMIN: adminA
    steps:
      - name: st1
        if: ${{ github.actor != env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: exit 1
      - name: st2
        if: ${{ github.actor == env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: echo "ok"
```

- in repo settings, add rule to protect 'main' branch. in that rule, select `'Require status checks to pass before merging'` and select `jobs` that you specified previously in github actions file. (if jobs not showing, try creating pull request that trigger those github actions, after that jobs will be found on search bar) (you can also select `'Include administrators'`)

  [image]

By doing that, changes are made to 'main' branch have to go through pull request and those checks will run and fail and prevent merging. Until the powerful collaborators (adminA, adminB) go to that pull request and re-run them, those checks succeeds and allows merging.
(The [pull_request_target](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) event makes `Github-actions` run on the context of base branch instead of the merging branch. So you don't have to worry github-actions file are edited to be passed easily from outside.)

Comment: Won't this allow collaborators to delete this action in their PR's? Which will make it all checks 'succeed' and allow them to merge?

Comment: @MartijnvdB It won't allow. the `pull_request_target` event I mentioned above will ensure github-actions file will be picked from main branch, not the merging branch. which means collaborators cannot modify actions from merging branch to make PR all passed

Answer (score 2):

It is posible by 'Branch protection rules':

[image: Branch protection Rules Section]

You have to select the branch you want to protect and select the people allow to merge in this option:

[image: Section to add people who can approve pull request]

Comment: You can clearly see in your screen shot that that feature is to control who can push to matching branches and has nothing to do with controlling who can merge.

Comment: @Sam is pushing not an integral part of performing a merge though? You have to push the resultant merge to the remote for it to be stored there, so perhaps this is actually the answer to the original question. I will have to investigate if it works.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock Did you have a chance to investigate this? Unfortunately this is difficult to test without a second account…

Answer (score 0):

I recall at least half of those features are in GitHub's settings. In your case, only approvers should be added as "collaborators", since they can `push`. Other users will have to open a `pull request` to make any change.

Answer (score 0):

@irous I followed your answer and it work for a single user, but then trying to specify for more than one user it is then required that the two specified collaborators must pass before a PR merge. Below is the added script:

```
  job1:
name: check_adminA
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
env:
  NAME_ADMIN1: pracin
steps:
  - name: st1
    if: ${{ github.actor != env.NAME_ADMIN1 }}
    run: exit 1
  - name: st2
    if: ${{ github.actor == env.NAME_ADMIN1 }}
    run: echo "ok"
job2:
name: check_adminB
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
env:
  NAME_ADMIN2: stephus
steps:
  - name: st1
    if: ${{ github.actor != env.NAME_ADMIN2 }}
    run: exit 1
  - name: st2
    if: ${{ github.actor == env.NAME_ADMIN2 }}
    run: echo "ok"
```

Comment: I wasn't notified by your tag. what is your issue exactly? do you want either ADMIN1 or ADMIN2 acceptance is enough? or both must accept?

Comment: @irous Yes I want either ADMIN1 or ADMIN2 acceptance is enough

Comment: you can just remove job2. In job1, st1, use '&&' to check both admins. in job1, st2, use '||' to check any of admins. [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)

Comment: Hello @irous I try editing the script to below, but I found out that it get passed no matter who is trying to merge, which defeat the plan, help check

name: actions_on_snapshot
on: 
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
    branches:
      - 'snapshot'

jobs:
  job1:
    name: merger
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ADMIN1: user1
      ADMIN2: user2

    steps:
      - if: ${{ env.ADMIN1 != 'user1' || env.ADMIN2 != 'user2' }}
        run: exit
      - if: ${{ env.ADMIN1 == 'user1' || env.ADMIN2 == 'user2' }}
        run: echo "ok"

Comment: I assume your expected result is to allow either admin 1 or 2. if so, in step1, try using '&&' instead of '||'. and 'exit 1' instead of 'exit'